# Execute a Python script inside Python and pass arguments to it and get the value returned

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to execute a piece of Python code [B] from my existing Python code [A]. 
In B I would like to access methods defined in A.
From A I would like to pass arguments to B.

If I try this way:

B.py

```
def Main(args):
   print(args)
   method_a()  # this doesn't work
```

A.py

```
def method_a():
   return 5
mod = importlib.import_module('B')
mod.Main(123)
```

Using import_module I do not have access to methods in A.py

If I use `eval` then I cannot pass any arguments to it and I'm not able to execute an entire file:
`eval('print(123)')` works 
but 
`eval(open('B.py').read())` does not.

If I use exec I can access methods from A.py but I cannot return any value or pass any arguments. 
I'm Using python 3.6

Comment: Why do you want this? I'm 100% certain that there is a better way to accomplish what you _actually_ need.

Comment: Why don't you just `import A` in `B.py`??? And yeah, you coudl use `importlib.import_module`, but that usually isn't the best, in any case though, if you *did*, you *definitely could use the functions in `A.py`. But `importlib.import_module` should work.

Comment: @Selcuk could you elaborate what other ways are there for me to execute python code?

Comment: Oh, I think I see, you mean `method_a` doesn't work. in `B.py` But of course not, and dynamically executing code isn't going to help that. `method_a()` as used in `B.Main` requires `method_a` to be in the global scope of the module. So, you *could* add `method_a` to the module object, but that is really not a reasonable thing to be doing. It seems like you should just change your approach

Comment: So Python, like pretty much all modern langauges, uses lexical scoping, which seems to be your fundamental issue. You want dynamic scoping. There's no way to do that other than ugly hacks like `mod.method_a = method_a; mod.Main(123)` in `A.py`, instead, `Main` could take the function *as a parameter*, that is how you should be communicating with a function from the caller. Not by hacking module namepsaces. Or again, just a re-design. Why are you trying to do it this way?

Answer (score 3):

Wrong design - two modules (or a module and a script - the only difference is how it's used) should not depend on each other. The correct way to structure your code is to have your "library" code (`method_a` etc) in one (or more) modules / packages that are totally independant of your application's entry point (your "main" script), and a main script that depends on your library code.

IOW, you'd want something like this:

```
# lib.py

def method_a(args):
    print(args)
    return 42

def method_b():
    # do something

# etc
```

And

```
# main.py

import sys
import lib

def main(args):
    print(lib.method_a(args))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```